# StringFormat in XAML with binding/function/format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string.format

I used to have this:

```
xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Pol.Wpf;assembly=Pol.Wpf"
Heading="{wpf:Translation Id=5589, Default=Evaluation on, IsUpper=True}"
```

This worked fine and gave me a the output:
"Evaluation on"

Then I needed to insert a date in the Heading, formatted:

```
Heading="{Binding EvaluationDateTime, StringFormat='{} Evaluation on {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}'}"
```

This gave me the Output:
Evaluation on 12-04-2016 10:12

Perfect, but I need to change my 
"Evaluation on" to use

```
"{wpf:Translation Id=5589, Default=Evaluation on, IsUpper=True}"
```

I have tried numerous things and just can't get my string to work in combination with a binding, stringformat and translate function. 
I need it to work with something like this:

```
Heading="{Binding EvaluationDateTime, StringFormat='{} {wpf:Translation Id=5589, DefaultTranslation=Evaluation on, IsUpper=True} {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}'}"
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the view model? If it must be in the XAML, I'd suggest you set the heading to a `TextBlock` that has two separate runs - the first your 'evaluation on' text and the next bound to the date using the `StringFormat`.

Comment: If I have to do it in the viewmodel, I will have to loop through a collection to  add a property as I am not allowed to change the model where the collection is coming from. And also the "Heading" is a dependency property on a custom usercontrol that is of type string. I did try <usercontrol.Heading> and inside it I tried <textblock>, but it complains that <textblock> is not recogniced as type string.

Comment: What is `Translation`? Is this a XAML markup extension?

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot be sure what the `Pol.Wpf.TranslationExtension` class looks like exactly and whether you have the ability to modify it, I'll propose a more versatile solution.

The idea is to subclass the `TranslationExtension` and provide the ability to format the value produced by the original extension. The code is short and simple:

```
public class FormattedTranslationExtension : TranslationExtension
{
    public string Format { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var baseValue = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider)?.ToString();
        if (baseValue != null && Format != null)
            return string.Format(Format, baseValue);
        else
            return baseValue;
    }
}
```

Then your binding would look like this:

```
Heading="{Binding EvaluationDateTime,
    StringFormat='{local:FormattedTranslation
        Id=5589,
        DefaultTranslation=Evaluation on,
        IsUpper=True,
        Format='{}{0} {{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}}'}"
```

The premise here is that our extension will produce a string `"Evaluation on {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}"` (or a translated equivalent), so that it can be used to format the date. Since we're using the `string.Format` method ourselves we need to escape the `{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}` expression by putting it in an extra pair of curly braces, hence we have `{{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}}`.

If you have access to the `TranslationExtension` class you can simply put this logic in it directly.